# Can't clone one SD to another with dd

Tags: linux, sd-card, dd, partition-recovery

I have:

1. Broken 32GB micro SD card - cannot write anything to it despite trying to force with (`hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc`):

   ```
   EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
   EXT4-fs (sdc1): INFO: recovery required on read-only filesystem
   EXT4-fs (sdc1): write access unavailable, cannot proceed
   ```
2. New 32GB micro SD card

If I try to `dd` whole /dev/sdc to file:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc*
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/hhome/os.img bs=4k
```

and put it back :

```
sudo dd if=/hhome/os.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4k
```

I get:

```
sdc: unknown partition table
```

while "broken sd" consists good partition table.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Can clonezilla clone it?

Comment: Did you format the "new sd card"?

Answer (score 0):

Your dd command will stop as soon as it finds a bad cluster. Use ddrescue or gddrescue instead, and don't forget to use a log file with it.

Comment: The error seems to come from the `umount` command. `dd` doesn't care about partition tables. It only sees bytes.